# PostgreSQL: Backend processes are active for a long time

Tags: postgresql

now I am hitting a very big road block.

I use PostgreSQL 10 and its new table partitioning.

Sometimes many queries don't return and at the time many backend processes are `active` when I check backend processes by `pg_stat_activity`.
First, I thought theses process are just waiting for `lock`, but these transactions contain only `SELECT` statements and the other backend doesn't use any query which requires `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock. And these queries which contain only `SELECT` statements are no problem in terms of plan. And usually these work well. And computer resources(CPU, memory, IO, Network) are also no problem. Therefore, theses transations should never conflict. And I thoughrouly checked the locks of theses transaction by `pg_locks` and `pg_blocking_pids()` and finnaly I couldn't find any lock which makes queries much slower. Many of backends which are active holds only `ACCESS SHARE` because they use only `SELECT`.
Now I think these phenomenon are not caused by lock, but something related to new table partition.

So, why are many backends active?
Could anyone help me?
Any comments are highly appreciated.
The blow figure is a part of the result of `pg_stat_activity`.
If you want any additional information, please tell me.

[image]

EDIT

My query dosen't handle large data. The return type is like this:

```
uuid UUID
,number BIGINT
,title TEXT
,type1 TEXT
,data_json JSONB
,type2 TEXT
,uuid_array UUID[]
,count BIGINT
```

Because it has `JSONB` column, I cannot caluculate the exact value, but it is not large JSON.
Normally theses queries are moderately fast(around 1.5s), so it is absolutely no problem, however when other processes work, the phenomenon happens.
If statistic information is wrong, the query are always slow.

EDIT2

This is the stat. There are almost 100 connections, so I couldn't show all stat.

[image]

Comment: 1) It happens sometimes when your query returns large amount of data from a table and you display that data on your query tool rather than inserting into other table or for any other operations. You shouldn't query to display large data

2) Or it might be because of the missing stats. Do analyze and Vacuum on that table. Can you post the query and the amount of data that it returns

Comment: Can you post the full stats? Please check the application name under pg_stat_activity which owns the process.
something like,                  
application_name | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
client_addr      | 127.0.0.1

Comment: Having a similar problem on production, sometimes the amount of active queries hits ±200. In my case all the queries are different and are querying different tables, but, same as in your case, are not locked by any writes. While investigating we tried to play with `work_mem`  and `shared_buffers` and it did really help. In your case I would go same way. We are monitoring our DB server via DataDog, if you have similar monitoring available, you should probably be able to tune the configs to help with your issue. We are using 9.3 though and non-partitioned tables.

Comment: If our cases are similar, you most probably have a problem with Postgres queue of reallocating memory to the processes. Just my guess. I'd really like to know how will you solve this problem so make sure to post back.

Comment: @Mohamed Anees A  See EDIT2. I showed, but why do you want see it? I don't understand why you want to check application_names.

Comment: @Sergey Telshevsky  Nice infomation! Today, I changed `work_mem` from 4MB to 32MB. However, the thing happened. And I don't change `shared_buffers` because `shared_buffers` is larger than 30% of full memory. In your case, how do you paly with theses parameters?

Comment: Go down with work_mem... if problem happens on many queries, from time to time most likely that is not the cause. More over - 200 connections with 32MB each - can interfere with other things.

Comment: I would go with shared buffers as well. That depends on your case, but - PG uses system cache, so in short you have that 30% of memory duplicated. More over - there is one writer. That is not that much problematic like with 8.x, but I would not make him busy that much.

Answer (score 3):

For me it looks like application problem, not postresql's one. `active` status means that your transaction still was not commited.

So why do you application may not send `commit` to database?

Try to review when do you `open transaction`, `read data`, `commit transaction` and `rollback transaction` in your application code.

**EDIT:**
By the way, to be sure try to check resource usage before problem appear and when your queries start hanging. Try to run `top` and `iotop` to check if `postgres` really start eating your `cpu` or `disk` like crazy when problem appears. If not, I will suggest to look for problem in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone.

I finally solved this problem.
I noticed that a backend process holded too many locks. So, when I executed the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = <pid>`, the result is about 10000.
The parameter of `locks_per_transactions` is 64 and `max_connections` is about 800.
So, if the number of query that holds many locks is large, the memory shortage occurs(see calculation code of shared memory inside PostgreSQL if you are interested.). 
And too many locks were caused when I execute query like `SELECT * FROM (partitioned table)`. Imangine you have a table `foo` that is partitioned and the number of the table is 1000. And then you can execute `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE partion_id = <id>` and the backend process will hold about 1000 table locks(and index locks). So, I change the query from `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE partition_id = <id>` to `SELECT * FROM foo_(partitioned_id)`. As the result, the problem looks solved.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> Sometimes many queries don't return
>   ...however when other processes work, the phenomenon happens. If statistic 
>   information is wrong, the query are always slow.

They don't return/are slow when directly connecting to the Postgres instance and running the query you need, or when running the queries from an application? The backend processes that are running, are you able to kill them successfully with `pg_terminate_backend($PID)` or does that have issues? To rule out issues with the statement itself, make sure `statement_timeout` is set to a reasonable amount to kill off long-running queries. After that is ruled out, perhaps you are running into a case of an application hanging and never allowing the `send` calls from PostgreSQL to finish. To avoid a situation like that, if you are able to (depending on OS) you can tune the keep-alive time: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE (by default is 2 hours)

Let us know if playing with any of that gives any more insight into your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late post, As @Konstantin pointed out, this might be because of your application(which is why I asked for your EDIT2). Adding a few excerpts,

- `table partition` has no effect on these locks, that is a totally different concept and does not hold up locks in your case.
- In your application, check if the connection properly `close()` after `read()` and is in finally block (From Java perspective). I am not sure of your application tier.
- Check if SELECT..FOR UPDATE or any similar statement is written erroneously recently which is causing this.
- Check if any table has grown in size recently and the column is not Indexed. This is very important and frequent cause of select statements running for some minutes. I'd also suggest using `timeouts` for select statements in your application. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/gin-intro.html This can give you a headstart.
- Another thing that is fishy to me is the JSONB column, maybe your Jsonb values are pretty long, or the queries are unnecessarily selecting JSONB value even if not required?
- Finally, If you don't need some special features of Jsonb data type, then you use JSON data type which is faster (magical maximum, sometimes 50x!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pooled connections not getting closed properly and a few queries might be taking huge time to respond back. As pointed out in other answers, it is the problem with the application and could be **connection leak**. Most possibly, it might be because of pending transactions over some already pending and unresolved transactions, leading to a number of unclosed transactions.

In addition, **PostgreSQL** generally has one or more "**helper**" processes like the `stats collector`, `background writer`, `autovaccum daemon`, `walsender`, etc, all of which show up as "postgres" instances.

One thing I would suggest you check in which part of the code you have initiated the `queries`. Try to `DRY` run your queries outside the application and have some `benchmarking` of queries performance.

Secondly, you can keep some ***timeout*** for certain queries if not all.

Thirdly, you can do [kill the idle transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT) after certain timeouts by using:

```
SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '5min';
```

I hope it might work. Cheers!